# What's the best approach to print a xml string in Grails to FusionCharts?

Tags: grails, fusioncharts

What's the best approach to print a xml string in Grails in this case:

Controller DashboardController.groovy:

```
package vs3

//import vs3.Navbar

class DashboardController {
    def index() {       
        def sinistralidadePSChartData = new String()        
        sinistralidadePSChartData = '<chart labelStep="2" caption="Monthly Report" subCaption="Unique Visitors" yAxisName="Visitor Count" xAxisName="Date" showValues="0" showShadow="0" formatNumberScale="0" showLimits="0" canvasBorderAlpha="0" showBorder="0" divLineAlpha="30" anchorRadius="4" anchorBgColor="0377D0" anchorBorderColor="FFFFFF" anchorBorderThickness="1" anchorAlpha="90" showPlotBorder="1" plotBorderThickness="4" plotBorderColor="0377D0" plotFillColor="0377D0"  plotGradientColor="" plotFillAlpha="20" bgColor="FFFFFF" showAlternateHGridColor="0" numVDivLines="2" toolTipBgColor ="DEF1FF" toolTipBorderColor ="2C516D"><set label="1 March 2014" value="490" /><set label="2 March 2014" value="510" /><set label="3 March 2014" value="1546" /><set label="4 March 2014" value="1250" /><set label="5 March 2014" value="1000" /><set label="6 March 2014" value="540" /><set label="7 March 2014" value="560" /><set label="8 March 2014" value="580" /><set label="9 March 2014" value="600" /><set label="10 March 2014" value="620" /><set label="11 March 2014" value="640" /><set label="12 March 2014" value="660" /><set label="13 March 2014" value="680" /><set label="14 March 2014" value="700" /></chart>'        
        render(view:'/templates/dashboard',model:[sinistralidadePSChartData:sinistralidadePSChartData])
    }
}
```

View/Template:

```
<g:applyLayout name="page">
    <h3>Dashboard</h3>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vs3/FusionCharts_XT_Evaluation/Charts/FusionCharts.js"></script>      

    <div id="chartdiv" align="left">Chart will load here</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var chart = new FusionCharts("Area2D", "ChartId","580", "400", "0", "0");           
        chart.setXMLData('${sinistralidadePSChartData}');
        chart.render("chartdiv");
    </script>

    <g:link url="/vs3">Voltar</g:link>
</g:applyLayout>
```

But it simply can't print all the quotes and all I can have is a badly xml/string badly printed in my page like:

```
chart.setXMLData('&lt;chart labelStep=&quot;2&quot; caption=&quot;Monthly Report&quot; subCaption=&quot;Unique Visitors&quot; (...)
```

How can I handle this issue?

Comment: Do you mean like: `chart.setXMLData('${raw(sinistralidadePSChartData)}');`

Comment: Cool :-)  Added as an answer, with a link to more options.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the raw unencoded output, you can do:

```
chart.setXMLData('${raw(sinistralidadePSChartData)}');
```

[See here for more options](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ie/2013/11/grails-goodness-generating-raw-output.html) :-)